# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined" - after calling ".start();" - plupload

Tags: javascript, plupload

Using plupload, I get the following error when calling .start().

[image]

From this line:

[image]

I am using RequireJS to handle the libary. Using latest version (v2.1.2). My code:

How my script looks like:

```
define(['jquery', 'plupload'], function($) {
    /**
     * Init
     */

        uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4', // gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus
            browse_button: 'uploadProfileImage',
            max_file_size: '2mb',
            url: ajax + 'uploadImage&temp=1',
            flash_swf_url: website_url + 'assets/js/lib/plupload/Moxie.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url: website_url + 'assets/js/lib/plupload/Moxie.xap',
            filters: [
                {
                    title: "Choose image",
                    extensions: "jpg,gif,png"
                }
            ],

            multipart_params : {
                type: '1'
            },
        });

        /**
         * Init file upload
         */

        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
            uploader.start();
        });


        uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function (up, files) {
            uploader.start();
            up.refresh();
        });

        /**
         * On callback (when file is uploaded)
         */

        uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info) {
            /**
             * Handle callback...
             */
        });
});
```

How my require config looks like:

```
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            shim: {
                plupload: {
                    exports: "plupload"
                },
            },

            paths: {
                jquery: [
                    'lib/jquery.min'
                ],

                plupload: [
                    'lib/plupload.full.min'
                ],
            }
        }
    });
```

The issues came up after migrating to RequireJS - previously it worked without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a problem with UA-Parser plugin. It thinks I am on Internet Explorer on Vista. But I am really on Chrome on OSX Yosemite.

This will in the end cause the function `_getNativeXHR()` (in Plupload) to mistaken me for being on Internet Explorer and this causes the crash.