# How to properly use Plupload with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, plupload

I am having a hard time finding documentation about how to use Pluupload (http://www.plupload.com/) with RequireJS.

The only thing I was able to find was this: http://pastebin.com/CKGNDDP1 - but its almost 3 years old, and a lot has changed since.

Currently my config is:

```
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            shim: {
                plupload: {
                    exports: "plupload"
                },
            },

            paths: {
                jquery: [
                    'lib/jquery.min'
                ],

                plupload: [
                    'lib/plupload.full.min'
                ],
            }
        }
    });
```

And on my page:

```
define(['jquery', 'plupload'], function($) {
    /**
     * uploader = new plupload.Uploader({......
     */
});
```

This almost works, as it does trigger the file upload, but once I call .start(); it breaks (as described here: ["Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined" - after calling ".start();" - plupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740050/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-open-of-undefined-after-calling)). Now I don't know if this has something to do with my setup, or the plugin, since it previously worked without RequireJS.

I use the latest version of plupload (v.2.1.2).

EDIT:

It looks like it already has support for RequireJS. Since I can remote the shim, and it still works. Is there any compatibility I should be aware of, by removing this, or is it safe?

Comment: No. I am separating the issues, since they are very different. One is about how to load the library correctly - another is about an potential bug in their code. Please reread my question, and you'll notice I've already linked to my "previous one". You solved nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a call to `define` in Plupload's code, which is what would be **required** to be present in the code *if* Plupload supported RequireJS.

So the shim is necessary.

However, your config is not correct. You've got `shim` and `paths` inside a top-level `paths`. They should both be at the top-level:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        plupload: {
            exports: "plupload"
        },
    },

    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'lib/jquery.min'
        ],

        plupload: [
            'lib/plupload.full.min'
        ],
    }
});
```